# select from a combination of rows that are filtered based on a criteria - pokemon data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, optimization

I have a 49x49 dataframe that looks like this

```
        normal fire water electric ....   max
normal       1     1     1        1       500
fire         1     1    0.25      1       400
water        1     4    1        0.5      450
electric     1     1    2         1       500
.
.
```

I want to find the combination of 6 rows that meet certain criteria.

1. For each combination of 6 rows (with repeats), find the column-wise highest value (excluding max column). If any of these values are lower than a set value, discard the combination.
2. For those 6 rows, add up the max column. Arrange the combinations in descending order of the sum of max.

Going through all the combinations 6 by 6 seems way too inefficient. I was wondering if scipy.optimize might be useful here, but don't know how I would set up the objective function.

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: This matrix seems to be symmetric, is it? Could the max be computed from the other columns? I think the best answer could be found if you could provide more details about those pokemon performance parameters ;-)

Comment: Hi @GuillaumeAnsanay-Alex. Nope, the matrix is not symmetric. The max can't be computed from the other columns, but its obtained by referring to another df. Would uploading a .csv of the matrix be helpful here?